# Shared pointers and const correctness

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, getter, const-correctness

Which is the correct way to extend the **const correctness** of a class to its pointed members? In the example code, is the constant version of the get method going to create an `std::shared_ptr` whose reference counter is the same as the internal member `m_b`, or is it starting again counting from `0`?

```
class A
{
    std::shared_ptr< B > m_b;

public:

    std::shared_ptr< const B > get_b( ) const
    {
        return m_b;
    }

    std::shared_ptr< B > get_b( )
    {
        return m_b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to also implement `get_const_b()`, analogous to methods `cbegin()` and `cend()` of standard containers (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shared_ptr` will always preserve reference counts when you construct from another `shared_ptr`; the only way to use it *unsafely* is to construct from a raw pointer: `shared_ptr<...>(my_ptr.get()) // don't do this` .

You may also be interested in the [`propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) wrapper, which is in the Library Fundamentals TS v2 so will probably be available in your implementation quite soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be deduced by doing some testing with `use_count()`.

Also notice how method resolution may be not completely obvious:

```
class B {};

class A {
  std::shared_ptr<B> m_b;

public:
  A() { m_b = std::make_shared<B>(); }

  std::shared_ptr<const B> get_b() const {
    std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
    return m_b;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<B> get_b() {
    std::cout << "non const" << std::endl;
    return m_b;
  }
};

int main(int, char **) {

  A a;

  std::shared_ptr<B> b = a.get_b();

  std::cout << b.use_count() << std::endl;

  std::shared_ptr<const B> cb = a.get_b();

  std::cout << cb.use_count() << std::endl;

  const A &a_const_ref = a;

  std::shared_ptr<const B> ccb = a_const_ref.get_b();

  std::cout << ccb.use_count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
non const
2
non const
3
const
4
```

Comment: Please, could you clarify what exactly is counter-intuitive here, and what kind of pitfall do you expect? The results seem pretty logical and safe to me.

Comment: One could think that the second call to `get_b()` resolves to the `const` version.  Also, the same ref counter is incremented by the third call, which is the answer to the question itself.

Comment: I rephrased my answer a bit, didn't mean to give so much emphasis on the pitfalls.

Comment: Thanks. The approach is safe after all.